# php special characters problem

Tags: php, magic-quotes

I am having a problem with the special characters in my script:

This is what I have so far:

```
$curlstrip = explode("&", $data);
$filename = substr(htmlEntities($curlstrip[5]), 2);
```

and if `$data` contains any special charaters like `&#39;` which is ', then instead of getting the chunk of string that I need, I get only the first part.
A more detailed example:

```
$data = "12er&sdsretdgsd&file=Chris ' 19 &blabla"
```

the script will read the ' after Chris as `&#39;` and `$curlstrip[5]` will have a different value.

Hope is clear enough.

LE. Following this example:

```
$data = "12er&sdsretdgsd&file=Chris ' 19 &blabla"
$curlstrip = explode("&", $data);
$curlstrip[0] = '12er';
$curlstrip[1] = 'sdsretdgsd';
```

but

```
$curlstrip[2] = 'file=Chris' instead of 'file=Chris ' 19'
```

and that is because the ' is being read as

```
&#39;
```

Thx,

Cristian.

Comment: Can you add a bit more detail about what you are doing - where the data comes from - and what you *intend* to do with it (where `$data` goes to)?

Comment: I can't change the format of $data, so I don't think it matter where is coming from. Thx.

Comment: $curlstrip[5] gets entered in a database, but my problem is that I can't get around these special characters.

Comment: @Chris you're still not giving enough information to give you a hint on what to do with the string. Maybe show the whole process and the point at which it crashes.

Comment: @Pekka the script almost works, except the part where, if the string contains single quotes they are being read as '$#39;'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
$curlstrip = explode("&", html_entity_decode($data));
$filename = substr(htmlEntities($curlstrip[5]), 2);
```

As I cant replicate your error given the code supplied, I have a hunch- try:

```
$data=str_replace("&#39;","'", $data);
$curlstrip = explode("&", html_entity_decode($data));
$filename = substr(htmlEntities($curlstrip[5]), 2);
```

If, for whatever reason, you have && (two ampersands) occurring in $data next to one another, it will interfere with the explode function.

Comment: Hmmm, using the code you've given- I cant replicate the problem with: $data = "12er&sdsretdgsd&file=Chris ' 19 &blabla";
$curlstrip = explode("&", $data);
print_r($curlstrip);

Comment: I think we are getting somewhere Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '95, The (1995-09-29)(SNK)(en-jp)[!][NGCD-084, NGCD-084E].zip', file_id = 'id0=0y' at line 1

Comment: @Ergo, using the script provided and adding '".addslashes($filename)."' before I enter the data in the database solved my problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Make htmlentities the last thing you call on the data.

```
$filename = htmlentities(substr($curlstrip[5], 2));
```

Aside from that there are functions to deal with what you're doing. [parse_str](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php) will create an array from a query string. [parse_url](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php) can be used to extract the query string from a url.

Comment: what do you mean by "Make htmlentities the last thing you call on the data"? Thx.

Comment: Same thing, I get only the first part of the $curlstrip[5], before the ' . I updated my question with more info. Thx.

Comment: Dont you want to decode, not encode the characters? This would produce more ampersands, not reverse back into say, apostrophes